# Can't create node with labels or properties here. The variable is already declared in this context in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried to run below cypher query in Neo4j(3 Merge Statement in once)

```
MERGE (paymentinstrument{SENDER_CREDITCARD:'123444'})-[rPAYMENTINSTRUMENT:PROFILECHANGE_PI{}]->( profilechange )                     
    ON CREATE SET rPAYMENTINSTRUMENT.CREATETIMESTAMP = toInt('1413911269726') 
    ON MATCH SET rPAYMENTINSTRUMENT.UPDATETIMESTAMP = toInt('1413911269726') 
MERGE (profilechange{PROFILECHANGEIDENTIFIER:'ABCD'})-[rPROFILECHANGEDEVICE:HAS_DEVICE{}]->( device )                                
    ON CREATE SET rPROFILECHANGEDEVICE.CREATETIMESTAMP = toInt('1413911269726')                                                         
    ON MATCH SET rPROFILECHANGEDEVICE.UPDATETIMESTAMP = toInt('1413911269726') 
MERGE (profilechange{PROFILECHANGEIDENTIFIER:'ABCD'})-[rPROFILECHANGEIPADDRESS:HAS_IP{}]->( ipaddress )
    ON CREATE SET rPROFILECHANGEIPADDRESS.CREATETIMESTAMP = toInt('1413911269726') 
    ON MATCH SET rPROFILECHANGEIPADDRESS.UPDATETIMESTAMP = toInt('1413911269726')
```

which encountered below error

> Can't create node `profilechange` with labels or properties here. The
>   variable is already declared in this context

Does anyone have idea or workaround for this issue ?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two merges starting with 
MERGE (profilechange{PROFILECHANGEIDENTIFIER:'ABCD'})
so, its like you are defining two references with the same name

second use, should be

```
 MERGE (profilechange)--
```

Also, you syntax is bad in the error prone sense.

In "Learning Neo4j", the author :) advises this syntax

```
 (reference:Label{key:'value'})-[r2:RELATIONNAME]->(reference2:Label{you:'got it'})
```

Comment: As I need to update the value of CREATETIMESTAMP and UPDATETIMESTAMP for each so I provide the property PROFILECHANGEIDENTIFIER in merge statement. so is there any way so I can tackle this issue and also update the value of CREATETIMESTAMP and UPDATETIMESTAMP

Comment: Empty brackets {} should be removed
Indeed, the code looks messy will all that capitals.

When you do a MERGE   node-rel-node, its the whole that is considered and rel in particular.

Want to change a node ? do MERGE (reference{key:value, key2: toIn(123132133) }) on the node